# Android AVD not recognizing device but ADB does

Tags: android, sdk, adb, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm trying to get my device to debug my software but it won't show up in the AVD list. The ADB can see it and so does the Eclipse device manager. I can get an interactive shell using adb etc.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb devices
List of devices attached
BX9038ZRUV      device
```

[image: ADV manager]

[image: Eclipse devices]
Does anyone understand what's going on and how I should fix it?
I'm running Windows 7 and my phone is a Sony Ericson Xperia S running Android 4.0.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

avd is only for virtual Device. What you have to do is: 
 Run Configs> change to "Ask everytime you run app" , or your real device.[image]

Answer (score 0):

AVD stands for Android Virtual Device, your phone is a real one. It should show up in the Select target list when you run or debug an application.

Answer (score 0):

The AVD list only the virtual devices (emulators). Select "Always prompt to pick device" in your [run config!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M00tT.png)

Comment: not that it really matters, but it's actually an emulator (not a simulator).  It tries to recreate the device instead of just act like the device.  That's why it's so slow.  /pedantic.