# Eclipse does not launch the Android emulator and won't install app

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I downloaded the 64-bit SDK ADT bundle from the Android developer website yesterday. I also downloaded and installed the 64-bit Java SDK 6. I've been trying to follow the tutorial on the Android site for building a Hello World app. I can create the app in Eclipse and I can also create an AVD. However when I go to Run as -> Android Application nothing happens. I am able to launch the Android emulator manually from Eclipse but I still can't get the app to install or do anything whatsoever.

There's no errors, no console output, nothing.

If I just click on the Run button I get this error: `Path for project must have only one segment`

Comment: Although this may not fix the problem, make sure Eclipse recognizes your AVD by changing to 'always prompt to pick device'. See if your avd shows up on the list or do 'adb devices' at cmd. [Details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103383/android-avd-not-recognizing-device-but-adb-does/13103414#13103414)

Comment: Its marked red in the picture. Next to your green 'run as' button.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the link. Unfortunately that did not work.

Comment: What do you mean by not work? Does the device show up in the list?

Comment: If I type `adb devices` at cmd my device is there but when I to go run config it's [not there](http://i.imgur.com/CMXiTfm.jpg?1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I found the problem. Under Properties > Run/Debug Settings I forgot to set the project name.

[image]