# can't find android device in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, android-virtual-device

I am running android adt bundle in ubuntu and I am unable to connect my Sony Xperia S and run the applications on it. I saw these pages for [setting up the hardware device](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html).I have set up the udev rules ,as stated in the instructions and I have been successful to run ./adb devices and  it gives a result as

```
List of devices attached 
CB511YVUQC  device
```

Even if the usb device is being shown but i can't see it in the AVD of eclipse.

Please Help.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Please check Devices list from eclipse. Check this page also [Android AVD not recognizing device but ADB does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103383/android-avd-not-recognizing-device-but-adb-does)

2.try **adb kill-server, adb start-sever**

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you need activate USB Debugging: Settings -> Applications -> Development - Enable USB Debugging

Answer (score 1):

Put your phone in Mass Storage mode(The default USB connection mode is MTP). After that, either reconnect the USB cable or try resetting adb.

Comment: Helped me, thanks. It's rarely mentioned on websites, but important.

Answer (score 0):

Reset ADB from within Eclipse, and your device should show up.

```
In Eclipse, open the 'DDMS' Perspective, in the 'Devices' tab, in the far right, there is a triangle, inside of that, select 'Reset ADB'
```

Comment: Before resetting the ADB, there was a sony ericson devicce entry in the DDMS Perspective. But I couldn't find it in the AVD Manager.

Comment: I cannot find anything in this list after removing all the workspaces metadata

Answer (score 0):

Go in platform-tools and type **adb kill-server** then **adb start-server** platform-tools is in your sdk in my case is E:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools